# Cannot log into my Mac because the password contains the symbols ¨^

Tags: macos, mac, password, login, login-screen

I am using a MacBook Pro 16 2019 (MacOS 13.2) and a very funny problem.

I created a new admin password that contains the symbols `¨^`, but in the login screen I can’t introduce those symbols, because when I press the corresponding key no symbols appears. Because of this, I am unable to log into the device.

The symbols on my keyboard from Spain are done with the keys right to ñ and p (see the attached image) while holding down Shift, but I suppose that in different countries the combination may differ.

I can't restore the admin password with my Apple ID because I have a firmware password to turn on the Mac, and I don’t remember that password. Without that password I cannot restore the admin password.

What would be the best way to solve this?

### More information about the symbols

Symbol  ¨ [diaeresis]
ASCII code  249
HTML entity &uml
Unicode U+00A8

Symbol  ^ [circumflex]
ASCII code  94
HTML entity ^
Unicode U+005E

[image]

Comment: Do you have an input format button in the toolbar on the screen you're seeing?

Comment: Get a Spanish USB keyboard so you can enter the symbols.

Comment: I tried with an english keyboard and the shortcuts “shift+opt+ u”, “shift+opt+ i” to add the symbols I mentioned. Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it didn’t work, the password is still not valid. I don’t know what to do right now,

Comment: Are you able to open "Accessibility menu" using ⌘⌥F5 ? There you'll be able to open software  keyboard and enter those characters.

Comment: You'd confused your dead-key commands. See answer below as to how to enter them.

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled SSH in the past (by default disabled), you could SSH into this Macbook and use the `passwd` command to reset your password from there.

Answer (score 1):

On a British English keyboard set to British or a US keyboard set to US English:

Diaeresis is generated by  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>u</kbd>  then  <kbd>[space]</kbd> 
Circumflex is generated by  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  then  <kbd>[space]</kbd> 
This will not type a space afterwards, it's like adding an accent to a letter using a dead-key combo, but without adding a letter, so it adds only the accent with no letter under it.

On an English keyboard set to Spanish **ISO** (not Spanish, which can't do both symbols directly, as a far as I can see.) [From comments, this may have changed in Ventura, but I can't test.]

Diaeresis is generated by  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd> 
[marked single quote on UK English keyboard, 2 keys right of L]
Circumflex is generated by  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd> 
[marked left square bracket on UK English keyboard, 1 key right of P]
Same physical locations as on a Spanish keyboard.

By the way, Macs don't use Windows-style ASCII codes at all.

Comment: Spanish ISO became  “Spanish” in Ventura I think.

Comment: @TomGewecke - ah, OK, thanks. Haven't used Ventura yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may reset your password with: three times wrong password, then "Reset Password using your Apple ID". There is also a possibility in Recovery Mode (restart with Command+R or with M1-Chip hold the power button until you see "options")